Duda sobre uso combinado de INSERT INTO
Estoy tratando de registrar datos desde un formulario que contienen 3 datos cargados según el usuario logeado, es decir, dependiendo del usuario que se loguee se muestran determinados datos específicos. Mi sentencia para guardar los datos son los siguientes:
Formulario:

Manejo de arreglo para guardar datos:

Cuando intento guardar los datos del formulario, los tres campos como: FONDO, SECCIÓN y SUBSECCIÓN se guardan sin problema en la base de datos, sin embargo, al momento de añadir el campo observaciones, no guarda ningún dato.
Mi duda es la siguiente, ¿Hay alguna sentencia para combinar INSERT INTO (value1, etc…) SELECT FROM usuarios (value1…) y poder insertar el campo “Observaciones”?
Este mensaje me arroja:


Saludos Omar. Cuando cargues información sobre tu pregunta, debe ser en código y no con imágenes. Te invito a realizar el recorrido de bienvenida, a que revises como preguntar y como formular buenas preguntas dando un ejemplo mínimo verificable. Intenta adjuntar las estructuras de tus tablas y datos para que algún miembro pueda intentar ayudarte.

Hola. Pon el código y los mensajes de error como texto por favor. ¿Cuál es la línea 27? ¿Dónde declaras a $idUser? Pon un echo $sql; y revisa la sintaxis de la consulta que se está produciendo. Tu problema es de primaria de depuración.

En el SELECT te falta observaciones. La tabla destino ¿tiene un identificador único?. ¿Esperas que la consulta regrese varios registros y y repetir las mismas observaciones?.

Podes agregar tranquilamente a tu select el campo observaciones como una cadena.. podrias agregar un update luego de ese select.. formas, hay muchas... probaste alguna??? de paso, no veo codigo en imagenes, es muy dificil de copiar y pegar...

Como ya te lo comentaron anteriormente, puedes concatenar ese campo como una cadena en tu instrucción SQL:
SELECT fondo, seccion, nombre_area, $observaciones as 'observaciones' FROM usuarios.......


Esta solución podría funcionar pero tiene un par de problemas: 1) ¿qué pasa si es una cadena? Como el valor no está entrecomillado, eso podría dar problemas. 2) es potencialmente vulnerable a ataques de inyección SQL.

Es correcto, tienes alguna otra solución?

Utilizando sentencias preparadas podría evitarse esa vulnerabilidad.
